# Android - Retrofit - File Uploaded to AWS S3 with pre-signed url is corrupt

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, retrofit

In my application, I need to upload images directly to AWS S3. For this my server generates a pre-signed url and mobile client use that url to PUT file on. Though getting 200 in upload call, the file is not uploaded correctly i.e. it's corrupt and never loads back.
Following is the code being used to upload file to S3.

```
public static interface FileUploadService {
    @PUT("/")
    void upload(@Body() RequestBody body,
                Callback<Object> callback);
}


ServiceGenerator.getUploadService(url).upload(
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), image),
                    new Callback<Object>() { });
```

I'm using Retrofit 1.8.

Comment: why not upload file from AWS s3 service, instead of using retrofit

Comment: is it happening in REST client?

Comment: @AbdulKawee I'm not getting what you want to say.

Comment: @PratikVyas I'm testing it on mobile. It's working fine on my webapp though.

Comment: okay, so can I assume that AWS S3 is accepting the request from webapps perfectly using the same API as your mobile platform does?

Comment: @PratikVyas yeah

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this if it helps but I used Retrofit 2,

**Gradle**

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
```

**The Interface**

```
public static interface FileUploadService {
   @Multipart
    @POST(HttpConstants.FILEUPLOADJSON1)
    Call<Result> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("stdID") int stdID);
}
```

**The Call**

RaytaApi service= RaytaServiceClass.getApiService();

```
    File file = new File(imagePath);

    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);


    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Call<Result> resultCall=service.uploadImage(body,INT_STDID);
    final Result[] result = {new Result()};

    resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            Log.v("@@@WWE","Respnse");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.v("@@@WWE","Failure ");
            Log.v("@@@WWE","MEssage "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

For complete example referance please visit 
https://github.com/pratikvyas1991/NetworkingExample-master

Comment: @Ammar does that helped

Comment: I couldn't update to Retrofit2 due to lot of other APIs needing to be revamped in that case. I've fixed this issue. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as following;

When using `RequestBody`, the `Content-Length` header was not carrying the correct info neither I was able to override it. So, I used `TypedInput` instead of `RequestBody`. My service interface looks like following.

```
public static interface FileUploadService {
    @PUT("/")
    void upload(@Body TypedInput body, Callback<Object> callback);
}
```

And image is uploaded as;

```
ServiceGenerator.getUploadService(url).upload(new TypedFile("image/*", file), 
                                              new Callback<Object>() { });
```